# Как перемножить уровни в структуре "дерево"?

Tags: php, рекурсия, дерево

Я строю дерево через рекурсивную функцию и у меня получается несколько уровней и мне нужно перемножить уровни в зависимости от коэффициентов умножения на каждом уровне. Например имеется дерево вида:

```
Уровень без коэффициента
1
    Уровень с коэффициентом 2
    1
        Уровень с коэффициентом 2
        1
```

Есть три единицы и их нужно сложить, но при переходе одной единицы на уровень выше её надо умножить на 2, то есть единица с третьего уровня на втором уровне превращается в 2, а на первом в 4 и т.д. То есть единицу с третьего уровня умножаем на 2, на втором уровне получившуюся двойку складываем с имеющейся на нём единицей 1 + 1*2 = 3, на следующем уровне 3 умножаем на 2 и складываем с имеющейся на первом уровне единицей. Должно получиться 7.
У меня получается только либо сложить их либо сложить и непонятно как перемножить. Ниже привожу код функции где у меня получается сложение.

```
function tree($id_blud)
{
    static $arr = array();
    $data = $this->getmysqldata('tree', $id_blud);
    $max = count($data);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $data_recalc = $this->getmysqldata('recalculation', $id_blud, $data[$i]['id_prod'], $data[$i]['id_obrab']);
        for ($j = 0; $j < 13; $j++)
            $arr[$j] += $data_recalc[$j]['recalc'];
        if ($data[$i]['vid'] == 1) {
            $this->tree($data[$i]['id_prod']);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Как правильно перемножить?

Comment: Как вы поняли что должно быть 7 ? при каком значении переменной  ` $max` у вас должно получится 7 ?

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan, цитата: "Должно получиться 7"

Comment: @Эдуард ага понял,то есть получается что пример приведен для 3 уровнвой вложнности,или там безграничная вложенность ?

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan, по описанию автора я сделал вывод, что речь идёт о трёх уровнях вложенности. Но если не ошибаюсь, моя рекурсия состоит из двух уровней, хотя и возвращает 7. И это не совсем соответствует условию.

Comment: @Эдуард Да уж лучше уточнить поподробнее.Ато иногда случается что тратишь кучу времени а им нe то надо было ,и в добавок ещо и минусуют :)

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan, если минусят, то я тогда удаляю свои посты )

Comment: @Эдуард Да но очки то снимаются безвозвратно .это  я плюсанул чтоб если что хотя бы по нулям вышел :))))

Comment: @Vanya Avchyan, благодарю ))

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял:

```
function foo($level) {
    static $i = 0, $j = 0;

    if ($j < $level) {
        $i *= 2;
        ++$i; ++$j;
        return foo($level);
    }

    return $i;
}

echo foo(3); # 7
```

Comment: @unit в результате 7.

Comment: Нет, это же дерево, уровней может быть любое количество и коэффициенты могут быть любые, как и цифры. Про единицы это просто пример. Нужна универсальная функция.

Comment: @unit, я переписал вариант в ответе - в вызов foo(3) передаётся число уровней рекурсии.

Comment: не пойму ничего.

Comment: @unit, скопируйте код и запустите на локальном сервере. Просто расписывать как он работает много дольше, чем посмотреть на результат.