# Дерево. Рекурсия. Хитрое перемножение

Tags: php, рекурсия, дерево

Здравствуйте. Делаю небольшой студенческий проект и у меня возникла трудность которую я не могу разрешить без сторонней помощи.
В проекте мне нужно в блюдо добавлять продукты из которых это блюдо состоит и на странице должна рассчитываться пищевая ценность блюда, в зависимости от вида обработки (Например у сырой картошки (условно) пищевая ценность: 0.6, вид обработки: варить, коэффициент для варёной картошки 2, тогда 0.6 * 2 = 1.2, далее складываем следующий продукт и т.д.). С этим у меня трудностей нет, трудность в том, что блюдо может состоять из других блюд и тогда это получается структура вида "дерево", в которой может быть любая вложенность. Я вытаскиваю данные из базы путём рекурсивной функции и, например, сначала картошку сварили, потом пожарили, а потом запекли (условно), т.е. блюдо состоит из 3-х вложенных блюд и у каждого своей коэффициент обработки.
Допустим пищевая ценность сырой картошки 1, коэффициент для варки картошки 2, для жарки 3, для запекания 4. Т.е. Сначала мы варим: 1 * 2 = 2, потом жарим варёную картошку: 2 * 3 = 6, потом запекаем жареную (до этого варёную) картошку: 6 * 4 = 24;

У меня не получается так перемножить все вложенности, у меня получается что каждая вложенность умножается только на коэффициент обработки своего уровня, но не перемножается с верхним по иерархии коэффициентом.

Вот моя неправильная функция:

```
    function tree($id_blud, $level)
{
    static $arr = array(); // статическая переменная в которой накапливается пищевая ценность
    static $ko = array(); // статическая переменная в которой сохраняются коэффициенты обработки вложенных блюд
    $data = $this->getmysqldata('tree', $id_blud); // данные о продуктах в выбранном блюде
    $max = count($data); // количество продуктов в блюде
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) { // проходим каждый продукт в блюде
        $data_recalc = $this->getmysqldata('recalculation', $id_blud, $data[$i]['id_prod'], $data[$i]['id_obrab']); // пищевая ценность i-го продукта
        echo "<div style='margin-left: " . ($level * 25) . "px;'>" . $data[$i]['nazv_prod'] . "</div>";

        if ($level == 0) // если вложенности нет
            for ($j = 0; $j < 13; $j++)
                $arr[$j] += $data_recalc[$j]['recalc']; // складываем пищевую ценность для каждого пищевого элемента (всего их 13: белки, жиры, углеводы, натрий, калий и т.д.) в статическую переменную $arr

        if ($level > 0 and $data[$i]['vid'] == 0) // если больше одного уровня вложенности, т.е. если блюдо в блюде, и это продукт, а не блюдо
            for ($j = 0; $j < 13; $j++)
                $arr[$j] += ($data_recalc[$j]['recalc'] * $ko[$level][$j]['ko_blud']); // складываем пищевую ценность для каждого пищевого элемента умноженного на коэффициент обработки вложенного блюда

        if ($data[$i]['vid'] == 1) { // если данный продукт является блюдом, то рекурсивно вызываем данную функцию и получаем коэффициенты обработки данного вложенного блюда
            $level++; // уровень вложенности
            $ko[$level] = $this->getmysqldata('tree2', $data[$i]['id_obrab']); // получаем коэффициенты обработки вложенного блюда для каждого пищевого элемента
            $this->tree($data[$i]['id_prod'], $level); // рекурсивно вызываем данную функцию
            $level--; // уровень вложенности
        }
    }
    return $arr; // возвращаем пищевую ценность всего блюда
}
```

Comment: посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668120/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE/668519#668519

Answer (score 0):

У вас тут кажется не правильно.
`$this->tree($data[$i]['id_prod'], $level); // рекурсивно вызываем данную функцию`
Вам нужно вашей функцией сделать входящий параметр или же ссылкой `&` или же когда он возращает данные их присваивать куда-то